# What is the default encoding for javac in Linux?

Tags: java, character-encoding

[javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javac.html#BHCBDCJI) says

> If the -encoding option is not specified, then the platform default converter is used.

I guess the default encoding in Linux is UTF-8, how to get the default encoding in Linux?

Answer (score 6):

[`javac`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javac.html#BHCBDCJI) will use the default encoding with which it has been *configured*.  Often this corresponds to whatever your system's default locale "codeset" happens to be, but there actually is no guarantee that they are the same.  The JVM does not pay attention to the locale environment variables.

The term "codeset" is (almost) synonymous with "charset set" or "encoding".

Further reading:

- [What Is a Locale?](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E26033/glmbx.html)
- [Re: Locale codeset UTF-8 vs. utf8](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-devel-list/2008-June/msg00287.html)
- [What is the default encoding of the JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006276/what-is-the-default-encoding-of-the-jvm)
- [Setting the default Java character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding)
- [How to Find the Default Charset/Encoding in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749064/how-to-find-the-default-charset-encoding-in-java)
- [how do I set the default locale for my JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-for-my-jvm)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's what you're asking, but you can see your encodings by running `locale`. Example:

```
malice@Haskell ~ $ locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Technically, `locale` does not show the encoding, but the encoding-name is by *convention* part of the locale settings.

Answer (score 1):

on ubuntu 14 , you can use this quick command:

```
    # env |grep LANG
```